# Trouble understanding tree recursion when we assign a variable to the recursive call

Tags: javascript, variables, recursion, tree

So these just sums the number of leafs node in a tree, but I have a huge problem trying to go through the second function and trying to visualise or even know whats happening. So, when we assign variable Left to LeafNode(node.left), does it call itself before we evaluate variable right, and if so or not how does work? I've tried with a debugger but it didn't do it step by step. Thank you!

Without variable assignment.

```
function LeafNode(node) {
    if (node === null) {
        return 0;
    } else if (node.left && node.right === null) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return LeafNode(node.left) + LeafNode(node.right);
    }
}
```

With variable assignment.

```
function LeafNode(node) {
   if (node === null) {
      return 0;
   } else if (node.left && node.right === null) {
      return 1;
   } else {
      let Left = LeafNode(node.left); 
      let Right = LeafNode(node.right);
      return Left + Right; 
   }
}
```

Trouble understanding the recursion process in the second function with variable assignment. From my understanding, when the variable left is assigned to the recursive function, we evaluate the function immedately, and do not evaluate the variable right until we are done, but for me the function would then only in the left subtree only check the left until the basecase but no in the left subtree check the right nodes. Is there a way to figure this out with any tools?

Comment: I think what you're missing is that each invocation of the function has its own copies of the variables. When you call the function recursively, it gets new `Left` and `Right` variables, which don't have anything to do with the variables in the caller.

Comment: Okay I think I know what you mean, because yes if we recursively call the function it will go through the function body each time and assign a variable to something in the body, but I don't have a clue what happens if we assign a variable to the function recursively, like it must evaluate itself before assigning to left is complete right? another example: let x = functionreturn2(2); - functionreturn2 will be evaluated and assigned to the variable x before continuing in the remaning program right? Thanks again for fast reply.

Comment: Yes, that's what happens with any function call in an assignment. There's nothing special about doing it in recursion.

Comment: But then we traverse the left subtree until basecase without remembering the right_subtree each call, right? Because with the first function, we have the return with +, so each call we still remember that we need to evaluate the right subtree each invocation. But is it the same with variable? That each call we still eventually need to evaluate the whole function body each recursive call? Also, how do you visualise or know this? Thank you

Comment: The two versions are essentially identical. The only difference is that the first one keeps the result of each call in an internal temporary location to be used with `+`, while the second one keeps them in named variables.